# Is there a Comet adapter around Play Famework 2.1 Websockets?

Tags: scala, websocket, comet, playframework-2.1

So I made this website to use websockets. All was good on my localhost and then I decided to deploy on Heroku. This broke the website because Heroku does not support websockets!

I wonder if anyone has written a simple adapter that allows me to use comet on the front-end and trick my Scala Play 2.1 server into thinking it's using websockets on the back end. Then I could use another adapter on the front-end to trick it into thinking it's using websockets as well and I wouldn't have to change too much code.

Comment: Cloudbees is rolling out websocket support in case you don't find your answer: http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/WebSocket+support

Comment: What about the Portal project for realtime webapp? https://groups.google.com/d/msg/play-framework/48CPZzb25fM/wH7iNkQ8qKsJ

Comment: Is that only for Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this using google: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ScalaComet

Is that what you need?